# How to set HTTP cookies with Twilio and Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, sms, twilio

I'm trying to use cookies to track SMS conversations with my node app, but they never seem to get set correctly. At least, when I retrieve them in the next text from the user, they're still null.

I have this function where it sets a cookie and sends a response to the user:

```js
function requestLocation (res, resend) {
    var locationXml = "";
    ...

    var responseText = "";
    ...
    
    var response = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    response.sms(responseText);
    res.cookie('rideStage', rideStages.SENT_REQUEST);
    res.send(response.toString(), {
        'Content-Type':'text/xml'
    }, 200);
}
```

But when I receive the next message from that user, "request.cookies.rideStage" is always null. I've also tried replacing

```js
res.cookie('rideStage', rideStages.SENT_REQUEST);
res.send(response.toString(), {
        'Content-Type':'text/xml'
    }, 200);
```

with

```js
res.send(response.toString(), {
        'Set-Cookie':'rideStage='+rideStages.SENT_REQUEST,
        'Content-Type':'text/xml'
    }, 200);
```

but, request.cookies.rideStage is still null.

Answer (score 3):

To anyone seeing this, what I posted above is actually correct.

By doing:
res.cookie('cookieName', cookieVal);

You can then use:
req.cookies.cookieName

to get cookieVal. The reason it wasn't working for me is because I was just testing my app locally and simulating a text with curl in the terminal, which totally excluded Twilio and cookie handling from the entire process (whoops).

Answer (score 0):

For the curious, we've also got a [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/07/the-definitive-guide-to-sms-conversation-tracking.html) about tracking SMS conversations with cookies.

And if you're looking to give it a try in Node get started with the [helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install) but don't forget to use something like [ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) to allow Twilio to see your app.